# Can someone please identify this SSD slot

Tags: ssd, motherboard, nvme, m.2

[image]

(Please look at the image) : I want to upgrade my laptop with an SSD but I can't identify the type of slot it has, It looks like it is an m.2 NVMe slot but most of the SSDs I have seen online have 5 pins and this slot seems to have 4, please can someone let me know what slot it is and it would be a bonus if you could link to any SSD online that would work with this slot. Thanks!

Comment: You should look at your motherboard or laptop manual to find out what it supports

Comment: I don't have the manual therefore I have uploaded the image please see if you can identify the slot, to me it looks like m.2 M Keyed, can you please verify that.

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop?

Comment: @DavidPostill Asus Vivobook Laptop (Core i5 8th Gen/8 GB/1 TB/Windows 10/2 GB) - X507UF-EJ092T

Comment: [Storage SSD M.2 for laptop X507UF | Accessoires Asus](https://en.accessoires-asus.com/laptop/storage/storage-ssd-m2/modele/x507uf)

Answer (score 0):

There are different sizes and keys of M.2 drives.  Here is a website that shows various connector types.  You will have to purchase an appropriate drive for that connector.

https://www.atpinc.com/blog/what-is-m.2-M-B-BM-key-socket-3

Comment: I have looked at the article and it looks like its an M keyed slot, can you please look at the image in the question and confirm the same, Thanks